# How to setup google analytics with google product search/google shopping?

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have already google product ads ups and runing and I can see some impressions and links in the adwords dashboard.

However, I cant see anything on the Advertising Tab in Google analytics

I used this method
http://blog.firstdigital.co.nz/how-to-track-google-shopping-traffic-reliably/

However, when I generate the feeds, I generate urls like this:
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/lexmark-fuser-for-c920-40x1056&utm_source=google&utm_medium=shop&utm_campaign=feed

and when I try it, it goes directly to the magento homepage

But I would like to know if there are better proven methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building the URL improperly. It would need to look like this.

```
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/lexmark-fuser-for-c920-40x1056?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shop&utm_campaign=feed
```

You need to have ? after the URI for the product.  I usually recommend this link to my clients and it will build URLs for you.  http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867

Answer (score 0):

as vern said in a url before the first parameter you need to have a "?"

```
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/lexmark-fuser-for-c920-40x1056?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shop&utm_campaign=feed
```

also Google analytics now will automatically track Google shopping in the adwords tab. Go into your adwords account and see which campaign has your product listings ads. You will find the Google analytics tracking under the same campaign name.

if you add Ga tracking to your urls then you will be duplicating the information in your Google analytics and you will count the metrics twice.